# javascript not working innerhtml

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Login - Loja do Munícipe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= stCSSFile %>" />
    <link href="../styles/cmm/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script language="javascript">

       function getbrowser () {
            var browser_info = {
                name: null,
            };

            if (navigator && (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()).indexOf("chrome") > -1) browser_info.name = "chrome";
            else if (navigator && (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()).indexOf("msie") > -1) browser_info.name = "ie";
            else if (navigator && (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()).indexOf("firefox") > -1) browser_info.name = "firefox";
            else if (navigator && (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()).indexOf("msie") > -1) browser_info.name = "other";

            if (browser_info.name == "ie" || browser_info.name =="firefox")
            {
            var linkinst = document.getElementById("ccbox");
                linkinst.innerHTML = "<div class=\"citizenCardCtr\" onmouseover=\"this.style.cursor='pointer';\" onclick=\"redirect();\"><h2>Autenticação com cartão do cidadão</h2> <p>Para escolher esta opção terá de ter em sua posse:</p><ul> <li>- Cartão do Cidadão;</li> <li>- Leitor do cartão, correctamente instalado no seu computador;</li> <li>- PIN da assinatura digital;</li> <li>- PIN da morada.</li></ul></div>";
                }
            else if (browser_info.name == "chrome")
                {
                var linkinst = document.getElementById("ccbox");
                linkinst.innerHTML = "<div class=\"citizenCardCtr\" onmouseover=\"this.style.cursor='pointer';\"><h2>Autenticação com cartão do cidadão</h2> <p> Esta funcionalidade não está desponivel no seu browser </div>";
                }


            }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .stylenumber
        {
            font-size: 14px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div id="mainCtr">
            <div class="boxesCtr">
                <div id="ccbox" style="font-size: 12px; color: #574529; font-family: Verdana; text-align:justify;"></div> 
            </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The `getbrowser` function doesn't work...when I load the page, the div with id="ccbox" shows no text with IE, Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: I don't see the `getbrowser` function being called anywhere.

Comment: are you... calling the function?

Comment: As has been said. You need to call the function from your HTMl. At the moment you have just created a function. However to use it you need to call it from the HTML. Unless I am missing something and you are calling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this before the definition of `getbrowser`:

```
window.onload = getbrowser;
```

Comment: Anywhere outside the function definition will do. Before or after, doesn't matter.

Comment: add it right before the function declaration: `function getbrowser(){`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this right below the `getbrowser` function definition:

```
window.onload=getbrowser;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this before defining getbrowser `window.onload=getbrowser;`

So it would look like this.

```
<script language="javascript">
window.onload=getbrowser;
function getbrowser () {
```

Answer (score -4):

Put your script in footer. it will work.

Comment: will still not work, the function he declared isn't being called.

Comment: Hi Friend, If you put your script in after the body it should work

Comment: otherwise you need to call the function in body onload

Comment: @AsaithambiPerumal: No matter where this code is placed, if you don't call the function somewhere, it won't be executed. And you can call it in the header and it will still work just fine. Personally, I put all of my Javascript code in the header (actually, mostly in external .js files, but those are also included in the header).

Comment: i am not answered for general case, in this case. they need to call the function after the page load. then only innerHTML will work. that means after document get ready

Comment: but you guys wrongly voted for me again and again. you need to test what i said. if you not understand my answer. just leave it as it is.

Comment: @AsaithambiPerumal: You said "Put your script in footer: it will work." If he takes the code that he has, and simply moves it to the footer, it will not work, because the function is still not being called. If what you meant was "call the function from the footer," then you need to say that. Simply moving his existing code to the footer won't do anything. Or perhaps you meant for him to just execute the code in the footer without putting it in a function. That would work as well, but you didn't say that either.